# Name of spinner/progress/indicator component

Tags: ios

On iOS when we press "Share" on videos, it starts processing the videos. When it does it shows a dialog with a circle spinner. Does anyone know the name of this component?

Here is screenshots:

## At about 10%

[image]

## At about 70%

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its called circular progress view in general. iOS framework doesn't provide such a component. The closest is UIActivityIndicatorView.

You can use an open-source MBCircularProgressBar: https://github.com/matibot/MBCircularProgressBar

Otherwise if you want to learn how its made than follow along Brian Voong's (Lets Build That App) tutorial on this topic here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3ltwjDJaMk

PS: Wait for the second episode of the tutorial series.